# Property of functions with same input => output independent of language or naming

Tags: programming-languages

Let's consider these four functions:

```
# Racket
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (sqr a) (* a a))

# Javascript
function square(x) {
  return x * x
}

function sqr(y) {
  return y * y
}
```

All functions square the given number but in different languages or with different naming. Output of calling any of them is always equal if given same input.

```
(square 4) == (sqr 4) == square(4) == sqr(4)
```

Is there any property that would describe such functions? Is there any way to prove if given functions have this property?

Comment: Not to nitpick, but "squere"? Is that a legitimate spelling somewhere?

Comment: Now that @Tulian has been downvoted, and I also posted a complementary answer, I need to ask for clarification. Your question seems to be asking about 2 properties: 1. Function's that consistently return the same output for a given input, and 2. That this holds across languages. Are you asking for a name that covers both?

Comment: Any algorithm trying to proof anything about functions almost always fails due to the halting problem. It may be possible to proof something in some individual cases - like the one above -, but it certainly cannot be done automatically for all cases.

Comment: @Carcigenicate With pure functions I am familiar and are not what I am after. Although, I assume property that I would like to find can be determined only for pure functions. Thank you for pointing out referential transparency. It seems like the most relevant candidate. I guess a better question would be now if functions can be found referential transparent across languages.

Comment: @Sjoerd thank you for mentioning halting problem. If focus is only on pure functions, do you think halting problem would also appear when finding out if two functions have the same meaning?

Comment: @Carcigenicate To answer your question directly, yes, I am looking for the name that covers your both points. And a way to find out if group of functions have this property.

Comment: @tomazzlender: Figuring out if two programs compute the same (mathematical) function is called the *Function Problem*, and is equally undecidable. In fact, the proof is relatively simple and uses the Halting Problem. Intuitively, imagine you have a program that doesn't halt (let's called it `infinite_loop`), and you have a solution to the Function Problem, then you could solve the Halting Problem by asking whether any program `p` has the same meaning as `infinite_loop`. Since we know the Halting Problem is undecidable, the Function Problem must be, too, otherwise we'd have a contradiction.

Comment: @tomazzlender See Jorg's answer. A proof without relying on the Halting Problem: Imagine two functions: one always returning 1, the other returning 2 when that algorithm compares itself equal to "always 1" and 1 otherwise. If the algorithm says those two are the same, they are not. If the algorithm says they are different, they act the same.So the algorithm cannot predict the equivalence of those two functions.

Comment: In fact, any algorithm strong enough to evaluate itself runs into this problem that it is possible to construct a contradiction by feeding itself as input to itself, whatever property one wants to proof. The only escape is when the algorithm is so weak that it cannot be applied to itself. But that requires the algorithm to be so weak, that it is useless in practice.

Comment: @tomazzlender in Python, would `lambda a: a * a` and `lambda d: d ** 2` have the property you're looking for? If so, would "equality" be the property you're looking for? Searching "equality of functions" led me to a Quora question that seems to refer exactly to the property you're describing, with an answer to that question explaining how it is / isn't decidable.

Comment: @user6245072 yes, these two functions would have that property. After pointing out term "equality" I found term "extensional equality" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality. This is the property I was looking for. I see that someone else asked related question here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22457/is-there-any-system-where-function-equality-extensionality-is-decidable

Comment: Another related discussion http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14132/is-it-possible-to-compute-whether-two-functions-are-extensional-equal

Comment: If you've found the answer and it's not already in one of the answers here, you're encouraged to [answer your own question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Such functions are referred to as [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Taken from the link:

> In computer programming, a function may be considered a pure function
>   if both of the following statements about the function hold:
>
> 1. The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any
>      hidden information or state that may change while program execution
>      proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it
>      depend on any external input from I/O devices (usually—see below).
> 2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output
>      to I/O devices (usually—see below).

As with all mathematical functions, when you square a number, not only can the output be 100% accurately guessed ahead of time, but executing the function doesn't cause any kind a state change; the entirety of the function is whatever it outputs.

This may be worth reading the following too, as it will give you more detail on this behavior:

[Referential Transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210835/what-is-referential-transparency)

Comment: I don't think it means pureness. I think it refers to the fact that those functions, given the same input, always return the same output, even if written in different languages and in different syntaxes. "Equivalent", or something along those lines, should be the term.

Comment: This seems to be very close to the term Idempotent, anyone care to clarify whether this is true or not and why?

Comment: @KellyS.French While I underestimated the importance of the language aspect when I answered this originally, I don't think "idempotent" fits here. See this link for a good definition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1077421/3000206.

Answer (score 0):

Functions that always teturn the same outoput given the same input are called **deterministic**.

Theu use deterministcis algorithms.

> In computer science, a deterministic algorithm is an algorithm which,
>   given a particular input, will always produce the same output, with
>   the underlying machine always passing through the same sequence of
>   states. Deterministic algorithms are by far the most studied and
>   familiar kind of algorithm, as well as one of the most practical,
>   since they can be run on real machines efficiently.

By extension functions that do this are called deterministic functions.

The quality of being deterministic is called **determinism**.

I don't know how to prove a function is deterministic other than testing ir and examining the code but non deterministic algorithms have some of the following:

> - If it uses external state other than the input, such as user input, a global variable, a hardware timer value, a random value, or stored
>     disk data.
> - If it operates in a way that is timing-sensitive, for example if it has multiple processors writing to the same data at the same time. In
>     this case, the precise order in which each processor writes its data
>     will affect the result.
> - If a hardware error causes its state to change in an unexpected way.

[Source.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm)

Comment: Never heard the word "deterministic" used in that way. A deterministic function will produce a predictable outcome, but it doesn't need to be side-effect free nor always the same result. Seeding a random generator and asking for the next few values is deterministic, but hopefully they won't all yield the same value.

Comment: @Sjoerd, I'd say that a deterministic function must be side-effect free, but won't necessarily give the same result on each call. What it must do, is give the exact same sequence of results for a particular starting state, such as a psuedo random number generator. So this answer is correct (if a little confusing).

Comment: @DavidArno The OP says (and I quote) "Output of calling any of them is always equal if given same input." So this answer is wrong. Besides, a pseudo random number generator is not side-effect free: it changes the seed, which usually is stored in some static variable.